# How to format colnames text in tableHTML package?

Tags: r, html-table, formatting, tablehtml

HTML is working fine in the rownames as well as in the caption and in the footer. Contrary to intuition in the colnames it's not working. How could I achieve equivalent formatting within the colnames?

```
mx <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, 
             dimnames = list(c("<i>&alpha;<sub>i</sub></i>", 
                               "<i>&beta;<sub>i</sub></i>", 
                               "<i>&gamma;<sub>i</sub></i>"),
                             c("<i>&Phi;<sub>i</sub></i>", 
                               "<i>&Sigma;<sub>i</sub></i>", 
                               "<i>&Tau;<sub>i</sub></i>")))
library(tableHTML)
tableHTML(mx
          , widths = rep(20, 4)
          , border = 0
          , rownames = TRUE
          , caption = "<b>Table 1: <i>&Phi;<sub>i</sub></i> and their <i>&Sigma;<sub>i</sub></i> and <i>&Tau;<sub>i</sub></i></b>"
          , footer = "<i>Note: </i><i>&Phi;<sub>i</sub></i>. Do re mi fa so la."
          , collapse = "separate"
          , spacing = "5px"
          , theme = 'scientific'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tableHTML` will escape `>` and `<` by default (HTML tags open and close where they shouldn't if they are contained within the data). So, you can just turn escaping off using the `escape` argument:

```
library(tableHTML)
tableHTML(mx
          , widths = rep(50, 4)
          , border = 0
          , rownames = TRUE
          , caption = "<b>Table 1: <i>&Phi;<sub>i</sub></i> and their <i>&Sigma;<sub>i</sub></i> and <i>&Tau;<sub>i</sub></i></b>"
          , footer = "<i>Note: </i><i>&Phi;<sub>i</sub></i>. Do re mi fa so la."
          , collapse = "separate"
          , spacing = "5px"
          , escape = FALSE
          , theme = 'scientific'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! BTW your package is really great, I love working with it; thank you very much for your work on this!

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind words @jaySf. Glad that you like it :)